# How do I apply XSL with Javascript when the XSL uses xsl:include?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'm working with the XSLT code sample on W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp

I have this section of code working in IE with basic xslt processing...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the XSL I'm scaling this solution for has a complex structure, so there are several xsl:include statements to pull in other xsl templates (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_include.asp). Javascript isn't processing the xsl:include imports and the XSLT processor keeps complaining about missing templates.

How do I get Javascript to process xsl:include?

Comment: Is that problem specific to IE? Which versions do you target?

Comment: I'm on IE 11, but I suspect this is more of an issue with xsl transformations where the xsl references other xsl files, along with how javascript loads them. I took all of the references out and put all the xsl in one giant file and it loaded fine. It works for a POC demo but I'd like to retain the original format if possible, but I'd have to get the files to load properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XSLT in IE and Edge through Javascript is a bit of a struggle as initially you would do that by using the various MSXML (Microsoft's COM based XML, XPath and XSLT 1.0 software package) components directly with the Microsoft specific `new ActiveXObject`. However, to be more compliant with other browsers they have, at least on the surface, moved to support `XMLHttpRequest` (in IE and Edge) and `XSLTProcessor` (in Edge), but as far as I understand under the hood it is still MSXML 6 that is used, in particular for XSLT.

As MSXML 6 by default sets the property `resolveExternals` to false the use of `xsl:import` and `xsl:include` fails, so to use MSXML 6 programmatically (in the browser you do that with Javascript) you first need to set that property to true to have MSXML then resolve and load external components like imported or included stylesheet modules. Only these properties are not well exposed when you load XML through XMLHttpRequest.

I have unsuccessfully tried to do that without resorting to too much IE specific code with the use of `new ActiveXObject` in https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2018/test2018112004.html (code visible at https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/blob/master/xslt/2018/test2018112004.html), however, when I abandon using XMLHttpRequest for IE (respectively where XSLTProcessor is not supported) and directly use all MSXML 6 components with `new ActiveXObject` and set the above named property, I get IE 11 on Windows 10 to resolve and use an imported stylesheet through Javascript in https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2018/test2018112005.html (code visible at https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/blob/master/xslt/2018/test2018112005.html). I haven't tried with earlier IE versions, other than trying to use the emulation mode in the IE 11 developer tools, based on that it also works with IE 10 and 9.

So what I do in

```
  function loadDocForXslt(url) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve) {
         if (typeof XSLTProcessor === 'undefined') {
           var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
           doc.setProperty('ResolveExternals', true);
           doc.onreadystatechange = function() {
               if (doc.readyState === 4) {
                   resolve(doc);
               }
           };
           doc.load(url);
         }
         else {
             var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
             req.open("GET", url);
             if (typeof XSLTProcessor === 'undefined') {
               try {
                 req.responseType = 'msxml-document';
               }
               catch (e) {}
             }
             req.onload = function() {
               resolve(this.responseXML)
             }
             req.send();
         }
       });
  }
```

is creating an MSXML 6 XML DOM document with `new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0')` directly and set is property `doc.setProperty('ResolveExternals', true);` so enable `xsl:import/xsl:include`.

Of course, as with most stuff you do in the browser, the same origin policy by default doesn't allow you to load XML from anything but the same origin your HTML with the script comes from.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution. I'm a little confused about the Promise object and how it's used in the xslProcessort.importStylesheets call to use the xsl. Can you explain that a little?

Comment: I am sure any Javascript guide on "promises" should help, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises. The main problem I delegated to the use of the Promise library or the built-in support for them is simply to make sure both the XSLT and the XML input are loaded asynchronously but the code to run the XSLT is only called when both documents (i.e. XML and XSLT) have been loaded, that's what the `Promise.all([loadDocForXslt(xmlUrl), loadDocForXslt(xslUrl)]).then(function(data)` does.

Comment: Doing asynchronous loading of a single document with the onload handler of XMLHttpRequest is easy without using promises but to load XML and XSLT asynchrously (which is considered good practice in client-side Javascript to not block the UI thread) but then perform the XSLT execution only when both are loaded seems like a good job for `Promise.all`.

Comment: Your solution is awesome but way more than I need or can dive into. I simplified the question over here if you have an extra min. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947155/how-do-i-load-xslt-stylesheets-in-javascript-so-include-is-processed