# How do I load XSLT Stylesheets in javascript so include is processed?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I'm loading an xslt stylesheet in javascript like this. I'm only required to support Chrome.

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename){
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

xsl = loadXMLDoc("../Stylesheets/main.xsl");
xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
```

main.xsl is the main stylesheet and contains a lot of xsl:include references to other xsl stylesheets. I need to send an argument somewhere that tells javascript to resolve the include references.

I'm not using IE, but it has an ActiveXObject method like:

```
doc.setProperty('ResolveExternals', true);
```

Is there some command I can put in my code to 'Resolve Externals' to pull in the stylesheets referenced in main.xsl?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out xhttp needed to be a global variable. I'm not sure why, but it worked.

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

Comment: "Turns out xhttp needed to be a global variable": in your code with `var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` you have ensured the variable is *local* to the function.